# How is $1/f$ called?

Tags: terminology, inverse

For numbers, one calls $\frac 1x$ the inverse of $x$

However, the inverse of a function $f$ is $f^{-1}$, i.e. the function which composed with $f$ gives the identity function

Is anyone aware of a name for the function $1/f$?

thanks in advance!

Comment: Multiplicative inverse of $f$.

Comment: It's commonly called the *reciprocal* of $f$.

Comment: Actually I would call $\frac 1x$, the *reciprocal* of $x$ to avoid this sort of ambiguity. You can use the same term for the reciprocal of a function.

Comment: "For numbers, one calls $\frac 1x$ *the* inverse of $x.$" Does one? Is $-x$ less of an inverse of $x$ than $\frac 1x$ is?

Comment: There is no particular name for $\frac 1f$. The only concern is that $f\ne 0$.

If $f(x)=c, c\in \Bbb R, \frac{1}{f}=\frac 1c$ is not a function. Might not even be defined if c=0.

Comment: of course, my question was about the case when f doesn't get the value 0 anywhere, otherwise there might be some unpleasant situations

Comment: by the way, $-x$ was called (by my professor) the {\it opposite} of $x$, so no confusion with the "inverse" $\frac 1x$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The term "inverse" is related to an operation. So if you define the operation of multiplying an object (say the function) $f:\mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ by (say the real number) $x$, i.e.

$$M f(t)= x \, f(t).$$

Then, the inverse of the operation $M$ is (usually) denoted by $M^{-1}$, and defined as

$$M^{-1} f(t) = \frac{1}{x} f(t).$$

Then inverse here means that $M M^{-1} f(f) = M^{-1} M f(t)=f(t)$. i.e.
$M M^{-1} = M^{-1} M =I$ where $I$ is the identity operation, that is $I f(t) =f(t)$.

Therefore, the inverse is for operations, and the reciprocal (1/x is the reciprocal of x) is the inverse of a particular operation, which is "multiplication."

**Note:** Division is multiplication by the reciprocal.

Note that

Comment: thanks to all of you for your input, reciprocal it is then! :)